# What cache should be cleared for front end theming work?

Tags: drush, caching

When theming I work with CSS files and templates files. What cache should I clear while retaining performance?

And what would be the equivalent drush command?

I think drush cc all clears too many things right?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the comprehensive list of cache-clear options and the underlying API functions & what they do:

- `drush cc drush` - [`drush_cache_clear_drush()`](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/commands!core!cache.drush.inc/function/drush_cache_clear_drush/7.x): Drush's internal cache for data from the Drupal install (e.g. available module commands).
- `drush cc all` - [`drupal_flush_all_caches()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_flush_all_caches/7.x): All Drupal caches.
- `drush cc theme-registry` - [`drupal_theme_rebuild()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/drupal_theme_rebuild/7.x): All theme metadata.
- `drush cc menu` - [`menu_rebuild()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_rebuild/7.x): All menu metadata.
- `drush cc css-js` - [`drupal_clear_css_cache()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_clear_css_cache/7.x) [`drupal_clear_js_cache()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_clear_js_cache/7.x): Aggreggated/Minified CSS/JS files.
- `drush cc block` - [`cache_clear_all(NULL, 'cache_block')`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_clear_all/7.x): All block metadata.
- `drush cc module-list` - [`system_rebuild_module_data()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_rebuild_module_data/7.x): All available modules (reloaded from file system).
- `drush cc theme-list` - [`system_rebuild_theme_data()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_rebuild_theme_data/7.x): All available themes (reloaded from file system).

That should let you fine target the cache to clear when it's needed.

Depending on your workflow, you might also want to force the cache off (e.g. `$conf['preprocess_css'] = 0;` & `$conf['preprocess_js'] = 0;`) in **local.settings.php** for your local dev environment so it doesn't interfere with feedback.

Comment: Can I force the cache off in backend performance options instead?

Comment: You _can turn it off_ there, but you can't force it; if you update your local site DB from a copy of your live site it will revert back to the same state as the live version.

Answer (score 1):

For CSS/JS you can do `drush cc css-js` in Drupal 7.